# insert new line after displayeing each key value pair in javascript object

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript object which is converted from json to java script object. i want to display its values like after each key value pair, i want to insert new line. but i dont know exactly how to do that. below is my code, please take a look and tell me how i should insert a new line. i tried but its not inserting a new line is diplay.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
    //timeout: 1000000
});

//String.prototype.toJSON;

//var the_object = {};

//function concatObject(obj) {
//    str = '';
//    for (prop in obj) {
//        str += prop + " value :" + obj[prop] + "\n";
//    }
//    return (str);
//}

function concatObject(obj) {
    strArray = []; //new Array
    for (prop in obj) {
        strArray.push(prop + ":\t" + obj[prop]+"*******************************************************\"\n\"");
    }
    return strArray.join();
}

//var input = "stephen.gilroy1";

function testCAll() {
    //var input = $('#Eid').val();
    //var input = $document.getElementById('Eid').getValue();
    //var input = $('input[name=Employee_NTID]').val();
    var keyvalue = {
    //ntid: $('#Eid').val()
        ntid:"ambreen.haris",
        name:"ambreen"
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Testing.aspx/SendMessage",
        data: "{}",
        //data: "{'ntid':'stephen.gilroy1'}",       //working
        //data: {'ntid': $('#Eid').val()},
        //data: {keyvalue},
        //data: { ntid: $('#Eid').val() },
        //data: ({ 'ntid': $('input[name=Employee_NTID]').val() }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result.d);
            resultData = eval("(" + result.d + ")");
            $("#rawResponse").html(concatObject(resultData));
            //$("#response").html(resultData.sn);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("jQuery Error:" + result.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with this?

```
function concatObject(obj) {
    var strArray = []; //new Array
    for (var prop in obj) {
        strArray.push(prop + ":\t" + obj[prop]);
    }
    return strArray.join("\n");
}
```

### EDIT:

You're appending HTML. So you should use `<br />`. Or surround the output with `<pre>` tags.

```
function concatObject(obj) {
    var strArray = []; //new Array
    for (var prop in obj) {
        strArray.push(prop + ":\t" + obj[prop]);
    }
    return strArray.join("<br />");
}
```

Comment: +1.. raw newlines would show up if the string was being added to a textarea.

Comment: However, amby didn't specify what `#rawResponse` referred to

Comment: Performance suggestion, push the prop, ":\t", and obj[prop] seperately along with a <br> and then use strArray.join("")